# Why R cannot find dependencies that are in the same local folder as the primary package?

Tags: r

Downloaded packages (in form of .tar.gz) to /tmp.  I have read, write, and execute permissions to all packages.  I try installing some packages (e.g. mapview), but R gives me an error

```
> install.packages("mapview.xyz.tar.gz", repos = NULL, dependencies = TRUE, type = "source")
ERROR: dependencies .... not available
```

All the dependencies listed in the ERROR message are present in the same folder as mapview package.  Unclear why R cannot find those additional packages.  Suggestions?

Comment: From the help file for `install.packages()`, take a look at `dependencies`. In particular this statement: `Not used if repos = NULL.`. I think you will need to manually install the dependencies in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam's observation is right.  Not being able to set repos = NULL when dependencies is set caused the problem.  Ultimate solution was to use a different function.  Following worked for me:

```
library(devtools)
install_local(...)  # added parameters that were relevant for my situation
```